# Integrating Cypress within TestRail

Tags: javascript, cypress, testrail

I've been trying to have my Cypress tests uploaded to their matching TestRail testcases, but so far it's not working.

---

Here's my current setup:

I have installed:

- **cypress**
- **cypress-testrail-reporter**

In my **cypress.json** file I have:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "my website URL",
    "projectId": "my project ID",
    "reporter": "cypress-testrail-reporter",
    "reporterOptions": {
        "domain": "https://customName.testrail.io",
        "username": "myemail@address.com",
        "password": "My API key",
        "projectId": 2,
        "suiteId": 12
    }
}
```

In Cypress, I have a **it()** block named **it.only("C170 Using wrong credentials", ...)**

In TestRail I have the following settings:

- API is enabled
- I have a custom API key (used in config.json)
- I am an admin user
- There's a testcase with the number C170

Then, when I run `cypress run --record --key my-record-key-from-cypress`:

- The tests appear in the Cypress Dashboard
- The tests **DO NOT** appear in the TestRail Dashboard

**Any idea what could be missing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SOLVED

Do not include **http(s)://** within your **reporterOptions** in the **cypress.json** file

```
BAD:   "domain": "https://customName.testrail.io"
GOOD:  "domain": "customName.testrail.io"
```

In all fairness, it's called **domain**, not **URL**, so I removing https makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You should also run the test from the CLI instead of the Cypress test runner.